# datetime printed in strange format

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I get this strange datetime format when I try to print it
`(datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 12, 15, 3),)`

```py
news = News(dateTime = datetime.strptime(new["date"], EU_SHORT_FORMAT))
print(news.DateTime)
```

but if query the object from the database and try printing that it prints out the actual datetime

---

I'm using sqlalchemy to manage the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to print the datetime object will print the object itself, and not the date. The object is what stores the date and time information, allowing you to retrieve it through different methods. Here are some examples of what you can do with a datetime object:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d  # this is what you see when you print the object
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 14, 9, 51, 56, 483458)
>>> d.ctime()  # an example built in method that formats the date and time
'Wed Jul 14 09:51:56 2021'
>>> d.isoformat(" ")  # this is equivalent to str(d)
'2021-07-14 09:51:56.483458'
>>> d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second  # storing the datetime allows you to get granular values
(2021, 7, 14, 9, 51, 56)
>>> d.timestamp()  # this is the number of seconds since 1970
1626281516.483458
>>> d.weekday()  # 2 means Tuesday
2
>>> d.strftime("%A %d, in the month of %B, and the year of %Y")  # strftime() allows you to format the date and time however you like!
'Wednesday 14, in the month of July, and the year of 2021'
>>> d.strftime("%d/%m/%y")  # in many different styles
'14/07/21'
>>> d.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
'07/14/21'
```

When you query the database, it uses one of these builtin functions to serve you a readable format of the date and time.